# How to learn advanced ms sql server?

Tags: sql-server, architecture, profiling

I have a strong database background but very little practical experience with ms sql server.
I want to learn the tools, the architecture, profiling and tuning.
Besides browsing around for little bits and pieces of information, I'm actually looking for larger guides. Books, training, series of articles, etc.
How do you recommend I start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to learn is by participating in newsgroups and forums. In the beginning you can just lurk but try to get information in...After a while you will notice that you know to answer some questions...start participating

get some good sql server books, if you can't afford books take a look at [Good SQL Articles To Read If You Can't Afford Books](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/good-sql-articles-to-read-if-you-can-t-a) there is some really good stuff here

Check out all the SQL Server [whitepapers](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/white-papers.aspx) available

Listen to sql podcasts [sqldownunder](http://www.sqldownunder.com/PreviousShows/tabid/98/Default.aspx) has 43 of them

Follow sql people on twitter and see what they link to, a list of people to follow on twitter can be found here [sql directory](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Twitter#Twitter_Directory)

I also interviewed a bunch of SQL Server legends like Ken Henderson, Kalen Delaney and more, you can find a list here: [All the interviews I did with SQL legends](http://denisgobo.blogspot.com/2008/12/all-interviews-i-did-with-sql-legends.html)

Answer (score 4):

Books and training is only one aspect.

Practical work is worth it's weight in gold. If you can get near a production environment with a live database and have access to a DBA willing to take you under his/her wing, take full use of the opportunity

Answer (score 3):

I use Expert SQL Server 2005 Development by Adam Machanic. Online tutorials are great too.  Especially ones that have video.

Comment: Have the same book, some really good stuff in there

Answer (score 1):

When I first started out with MSSQL I found the SQL2000 book from the Wrox "Professional" range to be a very good starting point, it might be worth you looking for if they have an updated edition. Everything else I've picked up frmo official documentation, other websites, and just kicking things to see what they do.

Comment: I used Professional SQL Server 2000 programming- that was a great book.

Comment: had the same book also had all the guru guide to SQL Server books by Ken Henderson and the Internals book by Kalen Delaney

Answer (score 1):

Start reading books. there are number of author who work hard to create the basic very clearly, and then if you feel that's not enough Internet is the best of all and has abundant material.